# Get Changes to ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have something like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_members
  has_many :tags, through: :tag_member
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_members
  has_many :posts, through: :tag_member
end

class TagMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :image
end
```

I want to track the edits on the `post` object. The easiest way to do this appears to be something like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_update :save_edits
  def save_edits
     # Assuming save_edit takes in a hash and persists it somehow
     save_edit(self.changes)
  end
end
```

However, from testing I've done, adding a new `Tag` to the `has_many association` on a `Post` does not run the before_update callback, and does not store anything in the hash returned by `.changes`.

What is the best way to track these types of edit as well? Should I simply overload the `.tags=` method to do my own storage, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class TagMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save { |t| t.post.save }
  # ^^^^

  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :post
  # ^^^^
end
```

Comment: While this does update the updated_at field, it does not run the ````before_update```` callbacks on the ````Post```` model, nor does it modify the ````.changes```` method on the instance of ````post```` being modified.

Comment: @SH.TheSuper What about now?